# jQuery send a post with redirect(simulate form submission)

Tags: jquery

I need to simulate form submission. I cannot submit form in an ordinary way because form is filtered depending on which fields user selected.

For example :

There is two types of advertisements(offer and request) and both of them has contact details with same fiels but if user selects first option (offer) when form is submitted empty values will be submitted because second one has contacts too.

Here is what I currently have:

```
var form = $('form[name=\'com_shareflat.offers\']');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // radio button with type(offer or request)
    var type = $('input[name=type]:checked', form);

    // user can enter login details or create new user
    var user_details = $('input[name=user_details]:checked', form);

    // each type is in separate container
    var data = type.closest('.form.container').find('input');
    // merging user details with type
    data.add(user_details.closest('.form.container input')).find('input');

    // here I need redirect sending post
    $.post({
        url : form.attr('action'),
        'data' : data.serialize()

    });
    return false;
});
```

Question: how can I simulate form submission only sending my own serialized data?

Comment: you can even send user to a router page then redirect him from that page

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to the url on success.

```
$.post({
   url : form.attr('action'),
   'data' : data.serialize(),
   success: function(){
       window.location = form.attr('action');
   }
});
```

Comment: This one will send post and on success will redirect to the action which is wrong because when I will send post, response will have validation messages which will be lost once redirect will happen